# Mapping list with 2D arrays using zip in Python

Tags: python, zip

I have the following labels and values and trying to get the Output below using the code:

```
lables: ['a','b','c']

values: array([[ 7963.92759169, -2931.3518914 ,  3360.79428745],
               [ 7964.28495515, -2930.99452794,  3361.15165092],
               [ 7965.60367246, -2929.67581063,  3362.47036823]])

for label, score in zip(lables,values):
   print("{}:{}".format(label,score)
```

Expected Output:

```
  a: 7963.92759169
  b: -2930.99452794
  c: 3362.47036823
```

But I don't get the expected output. Could anyone help on what is going wrong with the zip function?

Comment: Why would zip give you the diagonal of that matrix?

Comment: Perhaps you want to zip `values.diagonal()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code. Hope this would help.
Normally Zip function will give this ouput.

```
lables= ['a','b','c']

values= [[ 7963.92759169, -2931.3518914 ,  3360.79428745],
               [ 7964.28495515, -2930.99452794,  3361.15165092],
               [ 7965.60367246, -2929.67581063,  3362.47036823]]

for label, score in zip(lables,values):
    print("{}:{}".format(label,score[0]))
```

Output will be:

```
a:7963.92759169
b:7964.28495515
c:7965.60367246
```

But if you want diagonal elements then you have use a counter or you can use enumerate.

```
for index, (label, score) in enumerate(zip(lables,values)):
    print(score[index])
    print("{}:{}".format(label,score[index]))
```

Ouput will be :

```
a:7963.92759169
b:-2930.99452794
c:3362.47036823
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

lables = ['a','b','c']
values = np.array([[ 7963.92759169, -2931.3518914 ,  3360.79428745],
               [ 7964.28495515, -2930.99452794,  3361.15165092],
               [ 7965.60367246, -2929.67581063,  3362.47036823]])

for idx, (label, score) in enumerate(zip(lables,values)):
   print("{}:{}".format(label,score[idx]))
```

**Output:**

```
a:7963.92759169
b:-2930.99452794
c:3362.47036823
```